# Salva array float em um arquivo txt

Tags: python, string

Depois de salvar array em txt quero poder trabalhar com cada um dos valores fazendo todas as manipulações matemáticas, mas da forma q estou salvando não estou conseguindo. Alguém consegue me ajudar.

```
import numpy as np

xold = np.random.rand()
N = 3000

x0 = np.empty((N))

for k in range(N):
    x_new = 4*xold*(1 - xold)
    xold = x_new
    x0[k] = x_new

comp = len(x0)
aux = x0 + 0.25*np.std(x0)*np.random.rand(1,comp)

x2 = aux[0]

x3 = x2[1000:]
#X = x3[:-1]
A = x3[:-1].transpose()
D = x3[1:]

#-------- SALVAR EM TXT ---------------|
np.savetxt('A.txt', A, newline='\n')

with open('A.txt','r') as arq:
    aux = arq.read()

X = np.array([aux])
print(X[0])
print(type(X[0]))
print(X.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você salvou com `numpy.savetxt`, deve usar `numpy.loadtxt` para carregar:

```
np.savetxt('A.txt', A, newline='\n')
```

Depois...

```
A = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que queria fazer. Valeu